# Is it possible to change AlertDialog message only based on condition met?

Tags: kotlin, android-alertdialog

E.g. I have similar code to this post [Show AlertDialog if some condition is met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303446/show-alertdialog-if-some-condition-is-met)

```
if (condition) {

                AlertDialog.Builder(requireActivity())
                .setTitle("Internet")
                .setMessage("Internet ON")
                .setPositiveButton("ok!",null)
                .create()
            } else {

                AlertDialog.Builder(requireActivity())
                .setTitle("Internet")
                .setMessage("Internet OFF")
                .setPositiveButton("ok!",null)
                .create()
            }
```

But can I do the check for conditions met inside the message for dialog?
So that I do not rewrite same code twice, but with different message

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use ternary operator like syntax. Kotlin provides kinda the same logic, just a bit different syntax.

Here's an example.

```kotlin
AlertDialog.Builder(requireActivity())
                .setTitle("Internet")
                .setMessage(if (condition) "Internet ON" else "Internet OFF")
                .setPositiveButton("ok!",null)
                .create()
```

Read more here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46843369/3010171